# What's the difference between netstat and Powershell's Get-Process

Tags: powershell, tcp, process

What's the difference between `netstat` and Powershell's `Get-Process` and why I'm getting different results?

For example, on my machine running `netstat -a -n -o -b`, one of the processes is

> Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State         PID
>
> TCP    0.0.0.0:18882          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING   13708
>
> [System]

But running `Get-Process` I don't see any process with `Id` 13708.

Similarly, trying to kill this process (`Stop-Process -Id 13708`) returns an error message stating that:

> Stop-Process : Cannot find a process with the process identifier
> 13708.

EDIT:
The process is started by starting a proxy server ([Titanium-Web-Proxy](https://github.com/justcoding121/Titanium-Web-Proxy)) to capture browser traffic and the process I'm talking about remains in case the proxy is not stopped.

Comment: Unable to reproduce; getting same ID on `netstat`/`Get-Process` and can pass netstat process IDs to `Stop-Process`. Do you get the same error for other processes? Can't help noticing this process is `System`.

Comment: Did you execute both commands with admin privilege?

Comment: Yes, both commands were executed in a Powershell window started with Administrator rights (the old Run as Administrator option).

Comment: I can't reproduce this either. Can you start procmon, execute your netstat and get-process command and procmon and look (or post) in the trace for the PID?